# Sending Email with attachment without saving the attachment c# / ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, mailmessage

I am trying to send an email with an attachment that will be uploaded by the user and then sent to an admin email.

I have got this configured correctly on IE 11 but however with Chrome/Firefox there is limitations with the FilePath it provides. As IE 11 provides the full file path it allows my function to work.

Is there a possible way round this for Chrome/Firefox.

Mail Message code:

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage())
        {
                if (Attachment1.HasFile == false)
                {
                    message.From = new MailAddress(Environment.UserName + "@domain");
                    message.To.Add(new MailAddress("MyEmail"));
                    message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    message.Subject = "New Request from self service portal: " + Summary.Text.ToString();
                    message.Body = "Customer Name:</br>Customer Username:" + Environment.UserName + "</br>" + DetailedSummary.Text.ToString();
                    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
                    client.Host = "IP ADDRESS";
                    client.Send(message);
                } else {
                    message.From = new MailAddress(Environment.UserName + "@domain");
                    message.To.Add(new MailAddress("myemail"));
                    string file = Attachment1.PostedFile.FileName;
                    message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(file));
                    message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    message.Subject = "New Request from self service portal: " + Summary.Text.ToString();
                    message.Body = "Customer Name:</br>Customer Username:" + Environment.UserName + "</br>" + DetailedSummary.Text.ToString();
                    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
                    client.Host = "IP ADDRESS";
                    client.Send(message);
            }

        }
    }
```

This is where the user will specify which file will be uploaded and will not be a static file being uploaded every time. Meaning, i will need the filepath from the FileUpload.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336239/how-to-attach-a-file-from-memorystream-to-a-mailmessage-in-c-sharp

Comment: Try `System.Net.Mail.Attachment attach = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(Attachment1.PostedFile.InputStream, "filename");` then `message.Attachments.Add(`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`HttpPostedFile.FileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile(v=vs.110).aspx) *"Gets the fully qualified name of the file **on the client**."*

During development on your machine (and using a browser that actually sends the full path, which proper browsers don't) that may work, but as soon as you deploy it on a server it'll break.

The easiest way would be to use the [`new Attachment(Attachment1.PostedFile.InputStream, "attachmentname")` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sdktyws(v=vs.110).aspx) to directly stream the uploaded file into your attachment without having to temporarily save it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am looking into the input stream now. I will accept as soon as i have worked it out! Cheers again.