# Saving chart into image file with axis

Tags: c#, .net, image, charts, axis

can you tell me what is wrong with my code? I want to generate chart image in console application over System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting library... Following code generate me chart only with columns, but I need chart with axis. Any ideas?

```
Chart chart = new Chart();       

chart.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(2000, 500);
ChartArea area = new ChartArea();
chart.ChartAreas.Add(area);

chart.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;

chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "sasdasdasd";

Series series = new Series()
{
    Name = "series2",
    IsVisibleInLegend = false,
    ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column
};

chart.Series.Add(series);

foreach (CnbItem item in items)
{
    DataPoint p1 = new DataPoint(0, Double.Parse(item.Kurz));
    p1.Color = System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue;
    p1.AxisLabel = item.Kod;
    p1.LegendText = item.Kod;
    p1.Label = item.Kurz;

    series.Points.Add(p1);

}

string filename = "D:\\Chart.png";
chart.SaveImage(filename, ChartImageFormat.Png);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: Setting the the `Chart`'s `Backcolor` to `Transparent` actually works just fine. However some image viewers do not display transparency; I use **Irfanview** as my default viewer and it is one of those which can't. I suspect yours also misses transparency..

Instead **all transparency is rendered as black**, so unless you have a non-black line color.. your axes and labels etc.. **seem** to be gone. **Paint** (on W10) is another one but renders transparency to white, so the black pixels are at least visible.

The below image is from **Photoshop**, which, of course, doesn't have that problem..

[image]

Comment: thanks, this color works, but now this axisX labels are not under every columns, and values on axisY are not corrent :/ can you tell me why without creating new post pls ?

Comment: Well for this all the normal rules apply. Axis labels are usually put automatically depending on the available space. you can set an Interval as you like, `1` meaning every one unit..Not sure what you mean by  'values on axisY are not correct  (?)'. You can update your question with an image..

Comment: Well, I actually messed up the answer totally, see my update!

Comment: nice :) I could not add new answear so I try ask you one more question ...  can you tell me if is possible save chart image to stream ? I try this:
MemoryStream imgStream = new MemoryStream();
chart.SaveImage(imgStream, ChartImageFormat.Jpeg);
... create email client ...
mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(imgStream,"chart.jpg", "image/jpg"));
but this send email with attachment which is not possible open

Comment: I'm not familiar with the mail client but yes, the Chart.SaveImage explicitly has save to stream overloads. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336239/how-to-attach-a-file-from-memorystream-to-a-mailmessage-in-c-sharp) on attaching from a stream; you will need a streamwriter in addition to the memorystream.

Comment: This works here: `using (MemoryStream imgStream = new MemoryStream())
chart.SaveImage(imgStream, ChartImageFormat.Png);
imgStream.Position = 0;
System.Net.Mail.Attachment attach2 = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(imgStream, "image/png");
attach2.Name = "chart.png";
message.Attachments.Add(attach2);`