# Empty image wen i try to copy clipboard

Tags: vb.net

I have start to build my first software and i try to copy to clipboard a e.graphic draw in a panel
but wen i try to copy the image are empty
How can i copy my graphic to clipboard as a png image from paint event

This is my code.

```
Dim fileName = OpenFileDialog1.FileName

        Dim image1 = Image.FromFile(fileName, True)

        Dim texture As New TextureBrush(image1)
        texture.WrapMode = Drawing2D.WrapMode.Tile

        Dim font As New Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Bold)

        e.Graphics.DrawString(textoutline, FontDialog1.Font, texture, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text)
```

And i try to copy to clipboard with this code

```
Dim graphicsImage = New Bitmap(Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)
    Clipboard.SetImage(graphicsImage)
```

but i need to copy as png format how can i save it

Comment: As of now, you are sending to the ClipBoard a blank Image (there's nothing drawn on it, unless you're doing something else not shown here). Also, where is the `Paint` event? -- Since you have just started, do yourself a favor and set `Option Explicit On` and `Option Strict On` in all of your projects. Lots of headaches avoided (for example, you are passing `float` coordinates as strings in `e.Graphics.DrawString()`).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the image stored in memory is a bitmap. Why do you need it to be on the clipboard as a PNG? If it's just for the purpose of saving it to file, then you can use your already defined image object that you defined in this line ..

```
Dim image1 = Image.FromFile(fileName, True)
```

There is no need to store is as a PNG because you can save it in any of the supported formats .. Like so

```
    Image1.Save("filename", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
```

However, if you want to send the image as an email attachment, you could do something like the answer on [this Stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336239/attach-a-file-from-memorystream-to-a-mailmessage-in-c-sharp). Its in c#, but you get the idea.