# HttpContext is null when i call a method (Creation of an excel) from a Quartz.net job

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, razor, quartz.net

i have developed a mvc web app in asp.net i have created a quartz.net job to send an email daily in background and it all works great but i have a problem with the attachment, in another class i create an excel attachment and if i try to call that method in my job it give me error in that method that create the excel, i receive this error message in the HttpContext.Current code "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'"

This is my creation Excel code:

```
public static class CreazioneExl
{
    public static void CreazioneFile(ExcelPackage ex, string title)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            HttpContext cur = HttpContext.Current;
            cur.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            cur.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment ; filename=" + title + ".xlsx");
            ex.SaveAs(memoryStream);
            memoryStream.WriteTo(cur.Response.OutputStream);
            cur.Response.Flush();
            cur.Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my SendMailJob

```
public void SendMail()
    {
        ExcelPackage ex = ReportMethods.ExportExcelTotal(model);
        CreazioneExl.CreazioneFile(ex, "EmailXml");

        MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
        Msg.From = new MailAddress("mymail@hotmail.com", "Me");
        Msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("clientmail@gmail.com", "Client"));
        Msg.Subject = "Mail notifiche TrelloReporterApp ";
        Msg.Body = "Mail automatica di notifiche giornaliera";
        Msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        var filePath = @"C:\Users\me\Downloads\EmailXml.xlsx";
        Msg.Attachments.Add(new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(filePath));
        SmtpClient Smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com", 25);
        Smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        Smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        NetworkCredential Credential = new NetworkCredential("mymail@hotmail.com", "mypassword");
        Smtp.Credentials = Credential;
        Smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        Smtp.Send(Msg);
        File.Delete(@"C:\Users\me\Downloads\EmailXml.xlsx");
    }
}
```

And i wanted to start the mail job at the start of the application in the Global.asax:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        //other things

        //send email in background at the start of the application
        JobScheduler.Start();
    }
}
```

The creation of the excel works well when i use it in another context (print that excel that i create clicking a button) but when i use it in this background job i have that error that all the Http.Context is null... Can someone help me?

Comment: The `HttpContext.Current` only exists on incoming requests. Why do you need to write it to the response? You could write it to a `MemoryStream` and create the attachment from it: [MemoryStream Attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14839872/6666799)

Comment: because i use the method to create the excel for two different context, one is to print that excel file when you want by clicking the button in the index view, the other context is that i want to send a daily background mail with that excel as attaachment (but i wan to create it daily so if there are some changes i can send the correct excel with the last changes) sorry for my bad english,if you don't understand something tell me

Comment: @Rabban do you know how can i do?

Comment: @Bomber, unfortunately, there is no HTTP context in a background job.

Comment: @Bomber These are 2 different things, the first is sending a file as a http response, the second is sending a file as mail attachment. You can't combine them as one.