# Razor Pages Send Attachment with Webmail.Send

Tags: c#, email, razor, asp.net-webpages

I am trying to send the .ics attachment I created earlier via webmail.
Unfortunately I don't know how to convert it as a string array and even if I take a test string array it doesn't send the email out.
Does anyone know what the problem is?
Here is my code:

```
@{
  System.Text.StringBuilder str = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
            str.AppendLine("PRODID:-//Schedule a Meeting");
            str.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0");
            str.AppendLine("METHOD:REQUEST");
            str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTART:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(+330)));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTAMP:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", DateTime.UtcNow));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTEND:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(+660)));
            str.AppendLine("LOCATION: " + "abcd");
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("UID:{0}", Guid.NewGuid()));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("DESCRIPTION:{0}", "MY DESCRIPTIOsN"));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:{0}", "MY DESCRIPTION"));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("SUMMARY:{0}", "SUBJECT"));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("ORGANIZER:MAILTO:{0}", "Avenue 55"));

            str.AppendLine(string.Format("ATTENDEE;CN=\"{0}\";RSVP=TRUE:mailto:{1}", "msg.To[0].DisplayName", "msg.To[0].Address"));

            str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VALARM");
            str.AppendLine("TRIGGER:-PT15M");
            str.AppendLine("ACTION:DISPLAY");
            str.AppendLine("DESCRIPTION:Reminder");
            str.AppendLine("END:VALARM");
            str.AppendLine("END:VEVENT");
            str.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR");

            byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str.ToString());
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
           var filesList = new string [] { stream.ToString() };

           string body = "hey123";
            

            WebMail.Send(to: email,
                subject: "Hey111",
                body:  "test",
                filesToAttach: filesList);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [System.Web.Helpers.WebMail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.helpers.webmail.send?view=aspnet-webpages-3.2) `Send` method includes a `filesToAttach` parameter that takes a collection of strings representing the names of file to attach. It doesn't support adding a stream as an attachment. It was only ever designed to cater for simple scenarios.

You would be better off using the `MailMessage` and `SmtpClient` classes from `System.Net.Mail` and creating your email that way: [Attach a file from MemoryStream to a MailMessage in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336239/attach-a-file-from-memorystream-to-a-mailmessage-in-c-sharp)